# Make div with another divs responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am new at HTML and CSS and I want to make a responsive header that contains:

- logo picture with margin-left in pixels when full resolution
- pogo picture must have it's full size when full resolution
- navigation menu with 6

  and width of 1500 when full resolution

No Bootstrap. What are your suggestion to accomplish that? What I have made so far is not responsive, on full size (width:1920px) measures are fine and it looks exactly how it should, but when I try to resize browser it is not in one row, even if I declare that div "inner" that contains them is width:100%, and both of them are also width:100%.

Code is something like this:

```css
.inner{
      width:100%;
    }
    .navigation {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top:47px;
    padding-bottom:27px;
    max-width:1555px;
    width:100%;
    }

    .navigation li{
      display: inline-block;
      width: 16%;
    }

    .navigation ul{
      max-width: 1500px;
    }

    .wrapper-logo{
      display: inline-block;
      max-width:365px;
      width:100%;
    }
    .small-logo{
      max-width: 143px;
      width:100%;
      padding-left:220px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="inner">
       <div class="logo-wrapper">
           <div class="small-logo">
               <img src="https://99designs-start-attachments.imgix.net/alchemy-pictures/2016%2F02%2F22%2F04%2F24%2F31%2Fb7bd820a-ecc0-4170-8f4e-3db2e73b0f4a%2F550250_artsigma.png?auto=format&ch=Width%2CDPR&w=250&h=250">
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="navigation">
        <ul><li>......</li></ul>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: use @media screen for styling in different screen widths.

Comment: I usually write the mobile layout before the desktop layout,  I find the desktop layout easier to adjust. Furthermore the image that you chose is quite large for a navbar, I wouldn't use anything with a height higher than 50px. What you can do is that you can resize the logo and keep the ratio. If that suites you I can write you a solution

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries.

```
Here goes my Desktop resolution css 

    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    /* Here goes my Mobile resolution css */

        body {
            background-color: lightblue;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want something like the following for bullet 1

```
.small-logo {
    margin-left: 10%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .small-logo {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

Bullet 2 I'm guessing should say Logo not Pogo. Based on the code provided .small-logo is your only logo so you'd do something like this.

```
.small-logo{
    width: 100%
}
```

What does the navigation menu have 6 of? Columns? Buttons? Unicorns?

Set the inner class or **preferably an id** of the largest content div to the max I generally like to center the content and give some side white space so I put the basics in the comments.

```
.inner{
    max-width: 1500px;
    width: 100%;
    /*width: 85%;
    margin: auto 0;*/
}
```

Are you trying to have logo-wrapper and navigation horizontally aligned?

```
display: inline-block;
```